# Stuck at UV Mapping: mesh doesn't show in UV Window

Tags: uv

I'm migrating from 3DS Max to blender and its totally confusing.

Right now I'm stuck because when I do 'Mesh->UV Unwrap->Unwrap' nothing shows in the UV/Image editor window.

I did a render of some object and since then I don't see the mesh in uv coords.

I noticed  there were some kind of masks/layers and it's totally non-intuitive.

Here is a screenshot: so, how to see the UV mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see those mask icons on the bottom right corner of your UV/image window?

[image]

Select the one on the left and change it to view

[image]

Comment: A good tutorial on UV Unwrapping in blender can be found here:http://vimeo.com/77028835

Comment: Works, thanks. I also had to remove some pencil layer thingy :)