# Why doesn't UV Unwrapping show up?

Tags: uv

When I Mark the seams of the head mesh. And when I start UV unwrapping. It doesn't show  it on UV Editing window.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/stuck-at-uv-mapping-mesh-doesnt-show-in-uv-window or this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7889/why-doesnt-my-unwrapped-model-appear-in-the-uv-editor ? Your question is a bit unclear so many related ones may be mentioned. Probably adding some screenshots and info ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your object, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit mode.
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything.
3. If there's any image opened in UV / Image Editor, click "X" button in the menu header. This will unlink image from UV / Image Editor (the image still will be present in the file).

If the model was unwrapped, the UV map should now show up.