# What's Wrong with my UV editor?

Tags: uv

I've been working on this scene for a long time now but as I tried to put a skydome in, it would keep denying me the ability unwrap the top half of a UV sphere. I tried doing the same thing in a brand new scene and it worked, but not in the one I am currently stuck on. [image]

The UV editor is more of a rectangular shape than normal, which I believe is part of the problem. Basically I am asking how I can fix this so I can unwrap the top half of a sphere to create a skydome.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/stuck-at-uv-mapping-mesh-doesnt-show-in-uv-window

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at a render result. Click the "x" to clear it. 
[image]

Comment: That helped a lot, it's the little things that get me sometimes